# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/insert.php on line 30

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I am as green as green can be.  I'm trying to build a database for my DVDs.  Now I'm trying to build a form to enter the data.  I use Dreamweaver to code and it tells me there is a syntax error on the 'VALUE' line.  When I run the code I get the above error.  But the only ';' is at the end of the line.  I'm sure it's something stupid I'm doing wrong but I can't find an answer in any of your other questions or on your debugging page.  Thanks in advance and please be gentle... I'm new!

```
//  Write data to table.    

    $sql=("INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, BitRate, link)
        VALUES ('$_POST[Movies]','$_POST[Rating]','$_POST[Genre]','$_POST[Year]','$_POST[Actors]','$_POST[Time]','$_POST[Notes]','$_POST[Viewed]','$_POST[BitRate]','$_POST[link]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: X ' . mysql_error($con));
    }

 echo "1 record added";

 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: you are you using mysqli_query with mysql_error shouldn't it be mysqli_error. also if you are using mysqli_ you should be using prepared statements as this your current code offers no protection to SQL injection

Comment: `$var = ("string");` seems to not be a right syntax, however you are missing the last `)`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful there is an extra opening bracket:

```
$sql=("...
```

It should be

```
$sql="...
```

Comment: Thank you all so much.  The main problem was the "(" after $sql.  That took away the syntax error in Dreamweaver and the PHP script, alone, returns no error.  Now I get another error when I try to add the data to the database and I've tried my "VALUE" and the one with the concatenation periods and the both return the same error. Now I have more to read and try and solve.  You've all been great!

Comment: NEVER MIND!!  I feel like a kid with a new toy at Christmas.  I just forgot to upload the PHP file to the server.  It's working fine now with the VALUE line I originally had.  You folks are the BEST!

Comment: @JimRaymond Just try to keep your code readable (at least for you). This way you can detect and prevent many errors before they happen. And also try to learn how to decode what the error messages say. Usually they are very helpful (even if it wasn't in this particular case).

Answer (score 1):

**Modify Your query with this and use:**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, BitRate, link) VALUES ("'.$_POST[Movies].'","'.$_POST[Rating].'","'.$_POST[Genre].'","'.$_POST[Year].'","'.$_POST[Actors].'","'.$_POST[Time].'","'.$_POST[Notes].'","'.$_POST[Viewed].'","'.$_POST[BitRate].'","'.$_POST[link].'")";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { die('Error: X ' . mysql_error($con)); }
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `(` before anything that shouldn't be there.

```
$sql=("INSERT INTO movi...
     ^ // What's this?
```

You should have:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, BitRate, link)
        VALUES ('$_POST[Movies]','$_POST[Rating]','$_POST[Genre]','$_POST[Year]','$_POST[Actors]','$_POST[Time]','$_POST[Notes]','$_POST[Viewed]','$_POST[BitRate]','$_POST[link]')";
```

Alo, just FYI, normally when you get this `;` error, it means something is wrong on the line above.

Comment: That is great info to look on the line above.  I knew I got an error when I left out the ; on the line above.  Never thought about it for this one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replace your query with this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, BitRate, link)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['Movies']."','".$_POST['Rating']."','".$_POST['Genre']."','".$_POST['Year']."','".$_POST['Actors']."','".$_POST['Time']."','".$_POST['Notes']."','".$_POST['Viewed']."','".$_POST['BitRate']."','".$_POST['link']."')";
```

Comment: You were right on.  Thanks